# Reducing Volume of a background music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

In My application,I am playing a music using the following code.But i want to reduce the volume of the background music.How to do that.

Thanks,
Anish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out this...

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]setBackgroundMusicVolume:2.5];
```

Comment: reduce the value according to ur needs! :)